# How can I solve "NameError: name 'ArffDecoder' is not defined"?

Tags: python, file, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, attributes

**Hi I have written the following code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import arff as arf

file = open("final-dataset.arff")
decoder = arf.ArffDecoder()
data=decoder.decode(file,encode_nominal=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple arff-related packages. It's likely you installed arff ([project source](https://code.google.com/archive/p/arff/), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/arff/)) when, based on your use of the class `ArffDecoder()`, the one you are looking for is [liac-arff](https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff).

To fix your issue you need to uninstall arff and install liac-arff instead. arff needs to be deleted before you can use liac-arff as they both use the same name when you import them with `import arff`.